# Inverted Pendulum: model-based or model-free?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

This is my first post here, and I came here to discuss or get clarifications on something that I have trouble understanding, namely model-free vs model-based RL methods. I am currently implementing Q-learning, but am not certain I am doing it correctly.

Example: Say I am applying Q-learning to an inverted pendulum, where the reward is given as the absolute distance between the pendulum upward position, and terminal state (or goal state) is defined to be when the pendulum is very close to upward position.

Would this setup mean that I have a model-free or model-based setup? From how I have understood, this would be model-based as I have a model of the environment that is giving me the reward (R=abs(pos-wantedPos)). But then I saw an implementation of this using Q-learning (https://medium.com/@tuzzer/cart-pole-balancing-with-q-learning-b54c6068d947), which is a model-free algorithm. Now I am clueless...

Thankful for all responses.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Q-learning is model-free.

The idea behind reinforcement learning is that an agent is trained to learn an optimal policy based on pairs of states and rewards--this is in contrast to trying to model the environment.

If you took a model-based approach, you would be trying to model the environment and ultimately perform value iteration or policy iteration of the Markov decision process.

In reinforcement learning, it is assumed you do not have the MDP, and thus must try to find an optimal policy based on the various rewards you receive from your experiences.

For a longer explanation, check out [this post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-model-based-and-model-free-reinforcement-learning).